# How to add dates from the date updated in text box

Tags: javascript, html

I am using a form to input date in text box format (mm/dd/yyyy) and the next text box I will enter how many days to add. This is should automatically calulate the no of days and display in 3rd text box. E.g

Text Box1: Input date (mm/dd/yyyy)
Text Box2: Input no of days
Text Box3: textbox1 value+textbox3 value

I need help to add dates.

I tried in onblur event in textbox2 using Javascript function

Code:

```
//text box2 event
    onblur="adddate(this.value)"
//javascript fn    
    function adddate(a) {
        var rdat=document.telstoe.rdate.value;
        if(a==2) {
            document.telstoe.tdate.value=rdat+2;
        }
    }
```

Input Values:
Textbox 1: 11/14/2012 (mm/dd/yyyy)
Textbox 2: 2 or 3 or 4
The output should be: only the days should be counted and displayed and I am getting like 1/14/2012**2**

Please help with the correct code

Comment: ok, and? are u getting an error? Is it giving wrong dates?

Comment: Can you explain exactly what is happening that you are trying to fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
function adddate(a) {
    var tdate = document.telstoe.rdate.value;
    var theDate=new Date(tdate);
    theDate.setDate( theDate.getDate() + a );
    document.telstoe.tdate.value=(theDate.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + theDate.getDate() + "/" theDate.getFullYear();
}
```

and use this page for your reference:
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp

Please have a look at the object reference! It would be preferred for your own sake, to learn the javascript Date object. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks..I will try it and let you know

Comment: Text box1 date: 11/14/2012 (mm/dd/yyyy) Text Box2 value: 2 and using the same function Text Box value is: "Thu, 21 Mar 2013 18:30:00 GMT". I need the date in 11/16/2012 format. Can you help?

Comment: updated the answer - should work for you now. note it's the same as the answer @Matt gave you. please have a look at the Date object reference. cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [Date object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) to parse the date and add days to it:

```
var date = new Date(document.telstoe.rdate.value);
date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
document.telstoe.tdate.value = (date.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + date.getDate() + "/" date.getFullYear().toString().substring(2);
```

Or use something like the [jQuery UI datepicker](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker/formatDate) to format the date.